# User registration with admin authorization

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I was wonder if it is possible to include a way that when someone fill the user registration form to register, can the details be sent to an admin email for authorization before the user can login in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide any code I will guide you the process, you can later come back more specific question if you are stuck :

- Use the field `is_active` [provided by Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) from the User model to authorised access within your website.
- Extends the field `is_active` to set the default to False or set it to false in the begging of your user view
- Create a link with the ID of the user and a path to the Django Admin where you can update the user and active to True

In short yes, possible and pretty easy if you know a bit of Django.

Comment: ahh!!! that's what i was looking for, thank you for the help.